# Include copyright material used by permission in open source repository

Tags: gpl-3, github, multi-licensing

I've got an open source web project on GitHub licensed under GPL 3.0. Now I'm going to be adding some material under copyright (verses from a translation of the Bible) that I've been given permission to use. What are my options?

Can I put it in the public repo, but somehow mark the material (with a stricter license or that only I'm allowed to use it?)

Or do I have to either make the repo private or keep the material outside the repo.

Comment: What is the relation between the Bible verses and the rest of the repository. How useful would the repository be to me if I cloned everything except those Bible verses?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau The Bible verses are the core content of the repository/website. vonbrand's answer sounds like the safe way to go if I want to keep it public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If only you are allowed to use that extra material, keep it out of the repository. Say I (inadvertently, or on purpose, doesn't matter) grab that material, you could be liable for distributing it to me without permission.

Keep the private stuff in your own, personal, local (or non-public) repository; replace e.g. with choice phrases from [lorem ipsum](https://www.lipsum.com/) for mockup purposes in your public repository explaining the matter in README or some such.